# OpenVZ installation error on ubuntu

Tags: openvz

i am trying to install openvz on ubuntu,but when i use **vzctl set 10 --onboot yes --save** it gives error as **directory /proc/vz not found,assuming non openVZ kernel**

Comment: Ask at http://askubuntu.com/  may solve your problem faster.

Comment: Not a programming question - try http://askubuntu.com ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed openvz properly and booted into vzkernel ?

Try executing below command, it should work for openvz kernel:

> vzlist

if it doesn't that means server is booted with normal kernel and you need make changes in /etc/default/grub to boot openvz kernel.